# 'laravel' is not recognized as an internal or external command?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-artisan

I am trying to install laravel on windows.
after downloading laravel via composer

I tried to run laravel new command but I get this error:

```
'laravel' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I changed the environment variables but still cant run the command unless I go to the path and run it from there.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a new variable, you have to add the path to laravel to the `PATH` variable:

```
<old value of path variable>; C:\vendor\bin
```